# Set background panel size in ColorPicker?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to make a compact colorPicker with a limited number of colors. I've been able to do most of it but I can't find the property to set the size of the background panel.

Is this exposed to styling or programmatic control?

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    [Bindable]
    public var simpleDP:Array = ['0x000000', '0xFF0000', '0xFF8800',
        '0xFFFF00', '0x88FF00', '0x00FF00', '0xFF00FF', '0xFFFFFF'];
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Style>

    .mySwatchPanel {
    backgroundColor:#E5E6E7;
    columnCount:10;
    horizontalGap:0;
    previewHeight:20;
    previewWidth:20;
    swatchGridBackgroundColor:#000000;
    swatchGridBorderSize:0;
    swatchHeight:20;
    swatchWidth:20;
    swatchHighlightColor:#FFFFFF;
    swatchHighlightSize:1;
    textFieldWidth:72;
    verticalGap:0;
    paddingBottom:0;
    }
</fx:Style>

    <mx:ColorPicker id="colorPicker" 
                    swatchPanelStyleName="mySwatchPanel" 
                    dataProvider="{simpleDP}" 
                    showTextField="false"
                    width="40" height="40"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the `ColorPicker`'s `SwatchPanel` using the default style properties that are defined by the `swatchPanelStyleName` like this for example :

```
<fx:Style>
    .mySwatchPanel {

        backgroundColor:#E5E6E7;
        swatchHighlightColor:#FFFFFF;
        swatchHighlightSize:0;
        swatchGridBorderSize:0;
        swatchGridBackgroundColor:#000000;

        textFieldWidth:0;           

        previewHeight:20;
        previewWidth:20;

        columnCount:3;

        swatchHeight:20;
        swatchWidth:20;     

        paddingBottom:2;
        paddingTop:2;           
        paddingLeft:2;
        paddingRight:2;

        horizontalGap:0;
        verticalGap:0;

    }
</fx:Style>
```

this style will give you something like this :

[image]

of course you can play with these properties to get the size that you want, but don't forget that the default minimum size of the `SwatchPanel` is 100x100px.

But to overpass this limitation, you can use `mx.core.mx_internal` like this for example :

```
<mx:ColorPicker id="colorPicker" width="40" height="40" dataProvider="{simpleDP}" 
                showTextField="false" swatchPanelStyleName="mySwatchPanel" 
                open="colorPicker_openHandler(event)" />
```

and

```
protected function colorPicker_openHandler(event:DropdownEvent):void
{           
    // resize the SwatchPanel once then remove the event listener
    colorPicker.mx_internal::dropdown.mx_internal::setUnscaledWidth(62);
    colorPicker.mx_internal::dropdown.mx_internal::setUnscaledHeight(85);
    ColorPicker(event.target).removeEventListener('open', colorPicker_openHandler);
}
```

which will give you something like this :

[image]

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

See the **swatchPanelStyleName** style property, it must helps.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ColorPicker.html

Comment: eh, didn't look detailed. I think there is no solution, except your own "color picker" for this. This is normal for flash/flex.